# Remove "chapter #" from the chapter title but keep chapter number in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters

I am using `report` document class.
I want to remove word "Chapter" and "chapter number" from chapter title, so when new chapter starts I will get only chapter title. I can do it using:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
```

It looks ok, but it breaks the table of contents. I want numbered chapters on table of contents, e.g.

> 1. Function name one
>
> 1.1 Parameters
>
> 1.2 Returned value

but the table of contents looks like this:

> Function name one
>
> .1 Parameters
>
> .2 Returned value

I know I can do it using the package `titlesec`, but is there a way to do it without it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can redefine the internal way of the chapter output:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    %\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    %    \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
    %    \par\nobreak
    %    \vskip 20\p@
    %\fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
  \makeatother
```

Answer (score 15):

Basically you will want to renew the command that deals with the chapter title formatting. This [link](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/thesis/node10.html) explains it pretty well. Since you don't want the starred version, you can settle with changing the normal version.

```
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
 \vspace*{50\p@}%
 {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
  \hrule                                        % horizontal line
  \vspace{5pt}%                                 % add vertical space
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
   \huge\scshape \@chapapp\space \thechapter    % Chapter number
   \par\nobreak
   \vskip 20\p@
  \fi
  \interlinepenalty\@M
  \Huge \scshape #1\par                         % chapter title
  \vspace{5pt}%                                 % add vertical space
  \hrule                                        % horizontal rule
  \nobreak
  \vskip 40\p@
 }%
}
```

What you will want to do is comment out the line that has the `Chapter number` comment and the surrounding comments (everything inside of the if) to get rid of the extra space. You can customize this command a little further if you want to change the looks of the chapter headings. Take note that you have to wrap this in `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to change the catcode for the @ symbol. So you would get:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
  \hrule                                        % horizontal line
  \vspace{5pt}%                                 % add vertical space
  \interlinepenalty\@M
  \Huge \scshape #1\par                         % chapter title
  \vspace{5pt}%                                 % add vertical space
  \hrule                                        % horizontal rule
  \nobreak
  \vskip 40\p@
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

And a simple test document

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
  \hrule                                        % horizontal line
  \vspace{5pt}%                                 % add vertical space
  \interlinepenalty\@M
  \Huge \scshape #1\par                         % chapter title
  \vspace{5pt}%                                 % add vertical space
  \hrule                                        % horizontal rule
  \nobreak
  \vskip 40\p@
  }%
}
\makeatother
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
 some test text
\end{document}
```

Would look like this:

[image: toc]
[image: chapter caption]

edit: too slow :(