# How to add an item symbol before the caption

Tags: sectioning, symbols

how to add the blacksquare before the caption in LaTeX?

just like the itemize, but at the caption

## 1. Introduction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
{section}%                   % the name
{1}%                         % the level
{0mm}%                       % the indent
{-\baselineskip}%            % the before skip
{0.5\baselineskip}%          % the after skip
{$\blacksquare$~\bfseries\Large}} % the style
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section[foo]{MySection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You really shouldn't use `\bf` (see [l2tabu](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf)). The article class uses `\bfseries` to switch to bold instead.

Comment: @wh1t3: right. I fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package for customizing heading format and spacing, especially if there would be further requirements. Load the package, and use `\titleformat` for the format and `\titlespacing` for the spacing, described in the `titlesec` documentation.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\textbullet\thesection}{1em}{}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Text of introduction
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here you get a bullet as in itemize. For a black square, perhaps use `\blacksquare` of the `amssymb` package, as Axioplase wrote.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the chapter heading, have a look at [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30530/remove-chapter-from-the-chapter-title-but-keep-chapter-number-in-the-table-o/30539#30539) to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30530/remove-chapter-from-the-chapter-title-but-keep-chapter-number-in-the-table-o). That should be relatively easy to modify for your purposes, once you know that `itemize` uses a `\textbullet` by default.

For the section headings you can renew the `\section` command, which uses the `\@startsection` macro as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
{section}%                   % the name
{1}%                         % the level
{0mm}%                       % the indent
{-\baselineskip}%            % the before skip
{0.5\baselineskip}%          % the after skip
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\textbullet}} % the style
\makeatother
```