# need to change the way title chapters are displayed in 'report' document class

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I'm using the report document class and the chapter titles are very large, in bold font, and left justified. I need them to be 18pt, not bold, and centered. I also need the words 'chapter 1' to be centered above the chapter title. My preamble and chapters look like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing    % important!
\textfloatsep 0.75in                   % important with double spacing




\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter title}

\end{document}.
```

I have tried modifying as follows:

```
\centerline{\chapter{chapter title}}
```

or

```
\begin{center}
\chapter{chapter title}
\end{center}
```

but I don't think this is going to work...

Their are lots of posts related to this topic but I can't make sense of which exact parts to use for my application. Please help with my specific case.

Comment: Without loading any package you can redefine `\@makechapterhead`

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30530/remove-chapter-from-the-chapter-title-but-keep-chapter-number-in-the-table-o/30537#30537

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using [`titlesec`](ftp://sunsite.icm.edu.pl/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) package and `\titleformat` command:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Large\centering}{Chapter \thechapter:}{0pt}{}{}
```

where you choose what command to modify (`\chapter`), use vertical mode with zero spacing (`display` and `0pt`) and set font and centering (`\Large` is a 18 pt?).

Full listing:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \doublespacing
    \textfloatsep 0.75in

\usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Large\centering}{Chapter \thechapter:}{0pt}{}{}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{chapter title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for the clear and concise answer. I figured toe chapter titles now and I'm working on the section titles. I include the following in my preamble. \usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering}{CHAPTER \thechapter}{0pt}{}{}
     \titleformat{\section}[display]{}{\thesection}{0pt}{}{}. Now the section label (3.1 for example) and the section name (abstract for example) appear on different lines. How to fix...?

Comment: @user29753: Just remove the `[display]` for `\section`, this option enables vertical "mode".